# Problem using tar to create compressed archive

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I am running into the below issue.

I have two folders:
AD-VM and Jump-VM

In each of these folders, the contents are:

```
-rw-------. 1 root root  20G Jun 28 18:27 AD-VM-flat.vmdk
-rw-------. 1 root root 8.5K Jun 27 16:07 AD-VM.nvram
-rw-------. 1 root root  543 Jun 27 16:07 AD-VM.vmdk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Jun 27 16:07 AD-VM.vmsd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2.6K Jun 27 16:07 AD-VM.vmtx

-rw-------. 1 root root  20G Jun 27 16:16 Jump-VM-flat.vmdk
-rw-------. 1 root root 8.5K Jun 27 16:16 Jump-VM.nvram
-rw-------. 1 root root  545 Jun 27 16:16 Jump-VM.vmdk
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Jun 27 16:16 Jump-VM.vmsd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2.7K Jun 27 16:16 Jump-VM.vmtx
```

I am trying to compress each into a tar gunzip archive. 
I used:

```
tar -xzf AD.tar.gz AD-VM/*

tar -xzf Jump.tar.gz Jump-VM/*
```

After compression, I decompress on target and I only get the `flat.vmdk`
The other files are not available.

So I tried,

```
tar -xf AD.tar AD-VM
```

It archived the folder and I was able to see all the files. Then

```
gzip AD.tar.gz AD.tar
```

Again, it only ends up with the flat file.

Basically, my vmtx and other files are not available post decompression.

Comment: There are limitations of `tar`. I see 20GB file in your directories. Better try `zip`

Comment: Ah, was not aware tar had limitations. I will do a good old zip then. Thank you.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Um... I'm currently working with `tar` archives that (when compressed with `bzip2`) are larger than 500 GB.  A 20 GB file is not an issue for `tar`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the limitations are not (in linux) with the size of archive but with the size of files in it (IMO)

Comment: @RomeoNinov GNU `tar` version 1.12.64 or later will support files inside the archive of sizes up to 68 GB. Reference: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=25116

Answer (score 1):

With `tar`, `-x` is for extracting files from an archive, while `-c` is for creating an archive.

You said you tried the following to create the archives:

```
tar -xzf AD.tar.gz AD-VM/*
tar -xzf Jump.tar.gz Jump-VM/*
```

This should probably have been

```
tar -czf AD.tar.gz AD-VM
tar -czf Jump.tar.gz Jump-VM
```

Notice the `-c` instead of `-x` and that `/*` is not needed if you want to archive all files in the named directory.

Also, the command `gzip AD.tar.gz AD.tar` makes little sense. Why would you try to compress `AD.tar.gz`? To compress `AD.tar` to `AD.tar.gz`, just use

```
gzip AD.tar
```

Note that using `tar` with `-z` creates a compressed archive, so using `gzip` to compress it would not be necessary.